# How do I package my joomla 2.5 component with a plugin?

Tags: xml, plugins, joomla, components, package

I'm still learning joomla and I was wondering how do you install a plugin with a component in the pkg_youcomponent.xml installation [file](https://docs.joomla.org/Package). I've noticed with Joomla [image: Joomla 1.6] or higher it is possible to use the `folder="packages"` attribute on `files`.

I'm trying to package the [Rocket Theme RokBox Plugin](https://rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/rokbox) with my component. But I'm not having much luck.

Here is a zip preview of **pkg_autobase**.

[image: Zip preview of pkg_autobase]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/df43tkzb.2ib.png))</sub>

And here the package script based off [this](https://docs.joomla.org/Package).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<extension type="package" version="1.6">
<name>Autobase</name>
<author>Michael Jones</author>
<creationDate>May 2012</creationDate>
<packagename>autobase</packagename>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<url>http://www.triotech.co.nz/</url>
<packager>Michael Jones</packager>
<packagerurl>http://www.triotech.co.nz/</packagerurl>
<description>Package installer for AutoBase and RokBox Gallery Manager</description>
<update>http://www.triotech.co.nz/update</update>
<files folder="packages">
   <file type="component" id="autobase" >com_autobase.zip</file>
   <file type="plugin" id="rokbox" group="system">plg_sys_rokbox.zip</file>
</files>
</extension>
```

Now the thing I'm unsure about is.. the joomla 2.5 extension manager reports the error

```
    Install path does not exist
    Package Install: There was an error installing an extension: com_autobase.zip
```

But as far as I know I've packaged everything up correctly (both `component` and `plugin` install fine individually). Thus I'm wondering how do you correctly package a component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Each zip file referred to in the package xml must be a valid installation file.
2. The error is actually referring to the fact that your XML specifies that the zips are located in a directory called `packages` but your screenshot shows them on the same level as the package manifest xml.

You can fix this by either putting them in a directory called `packages` (the recommended way) or by removing the `folder="packages"` from the `<files>` element.

Comment: Thanks! lol I figured this out a couple minutes ago as well. I do have one question though now its working I keep getting `Another menu item with the same parent has this alias` is this expected?

Answer (score 1):

There should be packages folder which holds all the plugins and components,cos you were mentioned in xml as `<files folder="packages">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third-party component such as http://joomlatoys.com/index.php/toys/jtbuilder which can package the selected extensions and generate an installable archive for you.

Comment: This has actually been resolved; months ago... (see cppl response), but thanks.